# BigQuery: Rolling daily count visitor's summary of payment

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have this data:

| date | visitor_id | total_payment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | A | 20 |
| 2022-01-01 | B | 15 |
| 2022-01-01 | C | 20 |
| 2022-01-02 | B | 10 |
| 2022-01-02 | D | 25 |

I'd like to have daily count of visitor with total_payment equal or greater than 20$, with that being said, result I'm hoping is:

| date | count_visitor |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2 |
| 2022-01-02 | 4 |

2022-01-01 is 2 because only A and C have payment more than 20$, however on 2022-01-02 additional 2 more because B is 35$ (sum) and D is 25$.

Is there any possible query for this? I hope I'm clear on my description. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query as solution.
First, I calculate cumulative payments of each user.
Then, I find the minimum date for each user that exceeds 20$ cumulative payment.
At the last step, I count number of users for each minimum date, and also accumulate that number.
In the output you don't have to have first_day_users column, but I kept it to make it easier to understand the code.

So the output looks like that:
[image]

```
WITH 
data AS(
  SELECT "2022-01-01" AS date, "A" AS visitor_id, 20 AS total_payment UNION ALL
  SELECT "2022-01-01" AS date, "B" AS visitor_id, 15 AS total_payment UNION ALL
  SELECT "2022-01-01" AS date, "C" AS visitor_id, 20 AS total_payment UNION ALL
  SELECT "2022-01-02" AS date, "B" AS visitor_id, 10 AS total_payment UNION ALL
  SELECT "2022-01-02" AS date, "D" AS visitor_id, 25 AS total_payment
),
user_cumulatives as 
(
    SELECT
        visitor_id,
        date,
        SUM(total_payment) OVER (PARTITION BY visitor_id ORDER BY date) as cumulative_payment
    FROM data
),
user_first_dates as 
(
    select visitor_id, min(date) as date
    from user_cumulatives
    where cumulative_payment >= 20
    group by 1
)
select date, count(*) as first_day_users, sum(count(*)) over (order by date) as count_visitor
from user_first_dates
group by 1
order by date
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome @Indri

The query below will give you a running sum of the rows per day where the `total_amount` of greater than of equal to 20, I believe this should give you the answer you are looking for:

```sql
WITH data AS(
  SELECT "2022-01-01" AS date, "A" AS visitor_id, 20 AS total_payment
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "2022-01-01" AS date, "B" AS visitor_id, 15 AS total_payment
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "2022-01-01" AS date, "C" AS visitor_id, 20 AS total_payment
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "2022-01-02" AS date, "A" AS visitor_id, 10 AS total_payment
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "2022-01-02" AS date, "D" AS visitor_id, 25 AS total_payment
)

SELECT
*,
COUNT(*) OVER(ORDER BY date)
FROM data
WHERE total_payment >= 20
```

Comment: Sorry, I must have mistyped my data. Thank you for the help, but I meant to say that every visitor with payment more than 20$ is counted as 1, and it is cumulated daily. Your query only shows count for each day and will give me 2 count of visitor on '2022-01-01' and only 1 on '2022-02-01'. When I'm hoping it to be 2 and 3 (cumulated).

Comment: Aha, got it, will update my answer!